# How to set Kendo DropDownList list height from within a template?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Dropdownlist and I want to set it's list height property in a template. I don't know how to do that. Here is my existing template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendoui-template" id="dropdown-template">
<label for="#:field#DropDown">#:label#:</label>  
<input id="#:field#DropDown" 
    data-option-label="&nbsp"
    data-role="dropdownlist"
    #if (data.dataTemplate) {#
        data-template="#:dataTemplate#"
    #}#
    #if (data.cascade) {#
        data-cascade-from="#:cascade#DropDown"
    #}#
    data-text-field="#:text#"
    data-value-field="#:id#"
    #if (data.events) {#
        data-bind="disabled: showRequisitionList, source: #:field#DropDownDataSource, value: #:field#, events: {#:events#}"
    #} else {#
        data-bind="disabled: showRequisitionList, source: #:field#DropDownDataSource, value: #:field#"
    #}#
    data-animation="false"  

        >
</>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out a few things I was able to get the height configured by just adding the following to the template code. I hard coded it but should be able to make it a parameter and set each one dynamically.

```
data-height = "650"
```

Comment: I used this technique to change the drop down list height of a ComboBox :)

Answer (score 1):

Just write one line Code like :

```
  $("#dropDownList1").kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select Dropdown",
            dataTextField: "Dropdown",
            dataValueField: "Dropdown",
            height:"auto",
```

- meanse you write :height:"auto" . it will work Fine . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple Thing :

- Define Height inside Drop down list function like .

  Height:"auto";
- or Define dropdown class and Fix the height on CSS like
- HTML :-

  ```
     <input type="type" class="Dropdown" />
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
     <style>
         .Dropdown{
             Height:auto}
          </style>
  ```